# int object not callable in condional function

Tags: python, int

Here is a function which takes in an integer, tries to subtracts 21 from it, and returns the difference if the integer is less than or equal to 21 or double the difference if it is greater than 21.

The code works well until the integer value is less than or equal to 21. Beyond that it shows an error `integer object not callable`.

```
diff = 0
def diff21(n):
    if n <= 21:
        diff = 21 - n
    else:
        diff = 2(21 - n)
    return diff
```

Expected results:

```
diff21(21)-> 0

diff21(19)-> 2

diff21(23)-> 4
```

Comment: Hi, I paraphrased your question so others can understand the specific problem you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

2(21 - n) needs to be 2*(21 - n)

what "int object is not callable"  means here is that "2" is not a function you can call.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was a simple thing I just got confused

Answer (score 0):

2 * (21 -n) is what you need. The parentheses isn't a math operator. Think of it this way, it performs what inside the () before it continues outside. It could be a method call, like `func(1 + 2)` then func would take 3 as an argument.

P.s. diff outside your method is going to be different than the diff inside your method.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting this error is because of `diff = 2(21 - n)`. In most of the coding languages you need to specify the operation. This is mainly to avoid the ambiguity between multiplication/calling a function.

Example,

```
def x(a):
    print("ok.")
```

now `x(a)` would mean call to the function and not `x * a`

To correct your code,

```
diff = 0
def diff21(n):
    if n <= 21:
        diff = 21 - n
    else:
        diff = 2*(21 - n) #here
    return diff
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is when int n is greater than 21 the result within the parentheses will be negative which is why you are getting that error. You probably may need use the absolute value function and then multiply by 2. Like below:

```
diff = 0

def diff21(n):
    if n <= 21:
    diff = 21 - n
    return diff

elif n > 21:
    diff = 2 * abs(21 - n)
    return diff
else:
    print("Input not valid")
```